# Mocking scripts in python that run commands outside of functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, boto3

Found a script that import and run aws outside of a function:

```
$ cat script.py

import boto3

client = boto3.client("ssm")
...
```

Tried to mock like this, but didn't worked:

```
cat test.py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("script.boto3")
def test_boto(boto3):
    import script
```

When I run the script with pytest, I got an error from AWS.

Is it possible to mock script like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that is not possible to mock `boto3` or and entire module like `os`, but, it's possible to mock functions inside of the modules.

Example: Mocking `boto3.client`

script.py

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("ssm")
```

test.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

@patch("boto3.client")
def test_boto(boto3):
    import script
    assert isinstance(script.client, MagicMock)
```

Mocking `os.environ`:

script.py

```
import os
```

test.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("os.environ", {"TEST_ENV": "TEST"})
def test_environ():
    import script
    assert script.os.environ["TEST_ENV"] == "TEST"
```